# View with Not exists join to be used in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, not-exists

I need to create a view in SQL Server and to use it in a `GridView` on my `.aspx` page.
The view is mapped in my application through Entity Framework.

Here's my example:

```
SELECT User.UserName, User.UserId
FROM User 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT UsersInRoles.RoleId FROM UsersInRoles 
WHERE UsersInRoles.UserId = User.UserId AND UsersInRoles.RoleId = 'AdminRole')
```

The relation between `User` and `UsersInRoles` table is one-to-many.

I need to be able to pass the `AdminRole` value in my ASP.NET application.

I cannot use parameters in a view  (i.e. using `@Role` is not allowed).

Only views and tables can bind to a `GridView` so a stored procedure (where a parameter 
could be an option) is not good here.

Is there a workaround to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` maybe instead of the `NOT EXISTS`?
This way, having a `JOIN` on the `UsersInRoles` table, I could map the fields from `UsersInRoles` through Entity Framework in my application and I could add conditions there (with `EntityDataSource.Where` clause).

Comment: welcome to SO. Consider registering as a user. I have edited your question to make it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

For Exists, use the Any extension method in LINQ. For Not Exists, use !Any.

```
var query = from user in User
            where !user.UsersInRoles.Any(role => role.RoleId == 'AdminRole')
            select new {user.UserName, user.UserId};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new in EF, but I know that we can use stored procedures (or functions) in it.

[Try read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321)